# Diskpart command does not see my flash drive

Tags: diskpart

I start *diskpart.exe* from the command line. Then I run *list disk* command. Is there a way to make it see my flash drive?  I am on Win XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that XP's diskpart is unable to see flash drives. If you have access to a Vista installation, try it there.

Reference info about diskpart on XP being broken: [Vista on a stick: How to flash install your OS](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9013119/Vista_on_a_stick_How_to_flash_install_your_OS).

I hope this helps.